# Typescript generic modal

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, modal-dialog

I am writing a modal component for my React application. I want the modal props to be generic and consist of two properties `type` and `data`. The `type` tells me what type the modal is, and the `data` property tells me what kind of data it takes. I want the data to be dependent on the type, so whenever I specify the type I immediately know what data it uses. In other words I want to specify the modal data using the modal type.

For example, I got the following modal type:

```js
export enum ModalType {
  Payment = "payment",
  Alert = "alert",
}
```

I want the payment modal data to consist of the following properties:

```js
export type ModalPaymentData = {
  id: string;
  value: number;
}
```

and the alert modal data to be just `null`

```js
export type ModalAlertData = null;
```

Now I am trying to write the generic `ModalObject<T>` type which looks as follows:

```js
export type ModalObject<T extends ModalType> = {
  type: T;
  data: ...;
};
```

and based on the type I want to specify that this modal uses the data connected to that type. I managed to do it without generics, something like that:

```js
export type ModalPaymentObject = {
  type: ModalType.Payment;
  data: ModalPaymentData;
};

export type ModalAlertObject = {
  type: ModalType.Alert;
  data: ModalAlertData;
};

export type ModalObject = ModalPaymentObject | ModalAlertObject;
```

Is there any way to achieve this using generics? Maybe I could add the second type to my generic `ModalObject` type? I kinda managed to make it work this way

```
export type ModalObject<T extends ModalType, D> = {
  type: T;
  data: D;
};

const MObj: ModalObject<ModalType.Alert, ModalData[ModalType.Alert]> =
  {
    type: ModalType.Alert,
    data: null,
  };

type ModalData = {
  [ModalType.Payment]: {
    id: string;
    value: number;
  };
  [ModalType.Alert]: null;
};
```

But it's really redundant and it looks like the second generic type might be dependent on the first one.